Probability that maximum of two iid Unif(0, 1) r.v.s is less than the minimum of two other iid Unif(0,1) r.v.s?
Specifically, let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ ~ $Unif(0, 1)$. What is
$$P(\max(X_1, X_2) \lt \min(X_3, X_4))$$
Similarly, what is ?
$$P(\min(X_1, X_2) \gt \max(X_3, X_4))$$

With iid and continuous distributions, the two are equal.  Think of the $4!$ equally likely ways of ordering $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Making explicit the idea in Henry's comment, note that by exchangeability (which holds since the random variables are i.i.d.) we have
$$P(X_{\sigma(1)} < X_{\sigma(2)} < X_{\sigma(3)} < X_{\sigma(4)} )= P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < X_4) $$
for any permutation $\sigma:S\to S$ of the set $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$.
In particular, any order of the $X_i$ is equally likely. Since the total number of possible permutations is $4!$, we must have $P(X_{\sigma(1)} < X_{\sigma(2)} < X_{\sigma(3)} < X_{\sigma(4)}) = \frac{1}{4!}$ for any permutation $\sigma$.
Now, the probability that we are interested in is
\begin{align}
P(\max(X_1, X_2) < \min(X_3, X_4)) &= P(\text{both of } X_1, X_2 \text{ are less than both of }  X_3, X_4)\\
&= P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < X_4) + P(X_2 < X_1 < X_3 < X_4) \\&+  P(X_1 < X_2 < X_4 < X_3) +  P(X_2 < X_1 < X_4 < X_3)\\
&= 4P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < X_4)\\
&= 4\frac{1}{4!}\\
&= \frac{1}{6},
\end{align}
and you can do the same procedure for your other question.

Assuming that all four variables are independent, we know that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\max(X_1,X_2)\le z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le z,X_2\le z)=
\mathbb{P}(X_1\le z)\mathbb{P}(X_2\le z)=z^2
$$
for $0\le z \le 1$. Hence the density of $Z=\max(X_1,X_2)$ is $f_Z(z)=2z$, $z\in[0,1]$.
Similarly, for $0\le z\le 1$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\min(X_3,X_4)> z)=\mathbb{P}(X_3>z,X_4>z)=
(1-z)^2
$$
Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}(\min(X_3,X_4)>\max(X_1,X_2))=\mathbb{P}(\min(X_3,X_4)>Z)=\int (1-z)^2 f_Z(z) dz=\int_0^1 (1-z)^2 2z dz=\frac16.
$$
